# Google Closure Compiler - How to create an Extern for a variable (variable name can't change as it is in an Eval)

Tags: javascript, eval, extern, google-closure-compiler

I am using Google Closure Compiler in "SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS" mode. The JavaScript uses an "Eval" statement with the variable "_u" embedded in the string. When Google Closure Compiler obfuscates the code, the variable name is changed to "a" and I get an error that "_u" is not defined in the console. My understanding is that an Extern will solve this problem, but I'm not sure how to write it. Thoughts?

Code Snippet:

```
var FuncName = (function(){

  var ht=escape(_w.location.href)

  function _fC(_u){
    _aT=_sp+',\\/,\\.,-,_,'+_rp+',%2F,%2E,%2D,%5F';
    _aA=_aT.split(',');
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
      eval('_u=_u.replace(/'+_aA[i]+'/g,_aA[i+5])')
    }
    return _u
  };

  return {
  O_LC:function(){ 
    _w.open('https://someurl?referer='+_fC(_ht))
  }
};
})();
```

After Google Closure Compiler modifies the code:

```
var FuncName = function() {
  function a(a) {
    _aT = _sp + ",\\/,\\.,-,_," + _rp + ",%2F,%2E,%2D,%5F";
    _aA = _aT.split(",");
    for (i = 0;5 > i;i++) {
      eval("_u=_u.replace(/" + _aA[i] + "/g,_aA[i+5])");
    }
    return a;
  }
  escape(_w.location.href);
  return {O_LC:function() {
    _w.open("https://someurl?referer=" + a(_ht));
  }};
}();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only prevent renaming of global variables or properties with externs.  Locals will always be renamed.  You can modify the code in a number of ways to fix this, including using a function constructor:

`new Function("_u", "... function body ...")`

But I would rewrite the code to avoid using eval to construct the regex. This would work:

`_u=_u.replace(new RegExp(_aA[i], "g"), _aA[i+5]);`

You also may be interested in:

[Escape string for use in Javascript regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446170/escape-string-for-use-in-javascript-regex)

General documentation regarding the Closure Compiler limitations are here:

https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/limitations

Comment: Note, that you could also modify the compiler to special case "_u".  There is one such case already:
https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/blob/04dd916be73f961f489906231cfb1a1ad0fd583a/src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/CodingConventions.java#L327

Or propose a patch to make this configurable.

Comment: I'm using a plugin that uses google closure compiler, so I think I'm restricted to only passing in options such as '--externs=./lib/gcc-externs.js'

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy. You just need a separate externs file:

sampleextern.js

```
/** @externs */

var _u;
```

Externs are valid javascript. See http://blogs.missouristate.edu/web/2013/09/12/how-to-write-closure-compiler-extern-files-part-1-the-basics/

Comment: Chad this won't fix their issue though.  They won't their parameter "_u" to not be renamed.  The compiler doesn't support this directly.

Comment: @John I assumed since `_u` was not defined in the scope, the compiler would assume it was global, and therefore fall back to using the extern definition.

Comment: Yeah, this doesn't appear to work. Other options could be to rewrite the statement without the eval or to change the JavaScript, but this is 3rd party code and I have been discouraged from editing it. For now our team is using "WHITESPACE_ONLY".

Comment: _u is the function parameter, it is in scope.

Comment: @satoukum I would modify it and send a patch to the original author.