# How to prevent closure compiler from removing unused local variable?

Tags: google-closure-compiler

I am facing one scenario as below,

```
function a() {
  var $$ = this;
  eval("some script");
}
```

using closure compiler with simple level, it will remove the $$ var in the simplified output, but this variable maybe used by the code "some script" from script developers, so is there anyway to let closure compiler keep var $$ in the output? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Closure Compiler - How to create an Extern for a variable (variable name can't change as it is in an Eval)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33135183/google-closure-compiler-how-to-create-an-extern-for-a-variable-variable-name)

Answer (score 2):

Borrowing from [Solution: Export the Symbols You Want to Keep](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3#export) I suggest you use a bracket notation to create this var. I'm assuming that your global element is `window`.

`function a() {
  window['$$'] = this;
  eval("some script");
}`

It might not be pretty, but [this does work](http://jscomp-goro-public-hrd.appspot.com/home#code%3D%252F%252F%2520%253D%253DClosureCompiler%253D%253D%250A%252F%252F%2520%2540compilation_level%2520SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS%250A%252F%252F%2520%2540output_file_name%2520default.js%250A%252F%252F%2520%2540formatting%2520pretty_print%250A%252F%252F%2520%253D%253D%252FClosureCompiler%253D%253D%250A%250A%252F%252F%2520ADD%2520YOUR%2520CODE%2520HERE%250Afunction%2520a()%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520window%255B'%2524%2524'%255D%2520%253D%2520this%253B%250A%2520%2520eval(%2522some%2520script%2522)%253B%250A%257D%250A);

With an output of

`function a() {
  window.$$ = this;
  eval("some script");
}`

Comment: Not really local then

Comment: This has a number of problems, including that if '$$' is captured by some function in 'eval' the next call to 'a' can potentially change the value of '$$' and corrupt the previous result of the 'eval'

Answer (score 0):

No not really. You might be able to find a workaround, but it's not guaranteed to work in future compiler versions.

You would need to rework you code not to utilize eval like that.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Function constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function):

`var a = new Function('var $$ = this; eval("some script");');`

If you want to avoid escaping the contents of "some script", you can pass it in as parameter:

`var a = new Function('script', 'var $$ = this; eval(script);');`

This keeps needed locals out of the compiler's analysis.